# Copy contents from a master nsdictionary to another nsdictionary

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsmutabledictionary

Need to know the best way to copy the contents of an `NSMutableDictionary` into another `NSMutableDictionary`.

I have about 10 categories, that each have their own lists:

[image]

I have a `UITableView` that uses a class member called `listContent` as its `datasource`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *listContent;
```

I then need to save the contents of listContent into another list:

```
//Cached list results
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *listContentCategory1;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *listContentCategory2;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *listContentCategory3;
```

This is to save the overhead of fetching results that were fetched previously.

Simply doing `self.listContentCategory1 = self.listContent;` is not copying the current contents of `self.listContent` into `self.listContentCategory1`.

Should I be using `(nonatomic,copy)`, in `self.listContentCategory1,self.listContentCategory2?`

(1) How should I set up my properties for `self.listContent` and `self.listContentCategoy1,self.listContentCategoy2,etc?`

(2) Best way do the assignment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.listContentCategory1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: Self.listContent];
```

Make the properties (nonatomic, retain)